# How to display tiff, png images in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How to display tiff, png images in ASP.NET or windows application in IE browser.

Comment: Windows Application in IE browser?

Answer (score 2):

PNG is supported by all modern browsers. For TIFF, you may need to convert it to another supported format on the server.